# Adding the contents of UITextField to an NSMutableArray Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How can I put an element coming from a UITextField into an NSMutableArray by clicking a button in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your array and `UITextField` somewhere:

```
var textField: UITextField!
var array = NSMutableArray()
```

Then add this function:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked() {
   if let str = textField.text {
        array.addObject(str)
    }
}
```

It just adds text in `UITextField` to array if it's not nil.

And don't forget to attach it to `UIButton` in storyboard.

Comment: Awesome.! Thanks You.!

Answer (score 0):

your UITextfield and NSMutableArray..

```
var txtField: UITextField!
var aray = NSMutableArray()
```

your UIButton click event..

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked()
{
  if let string = txtField.text 
  {
     aray.addObject(string)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.! :D